# Instalar un paquete NuGet de nuget.org en windows server

Tags: packages, nuget

quiero instalar el paquete Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0. en mi servidor que es windows server 2019 Standard ya tengo descargado el archivo microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.3.6.0.nupkg pero no encuentro la manera de poder instalarlo, también leí que con nuget.exe se podian instalar paquetes pero lo descargo y al momento de ejecutarlo solo lo ejecuta pero en después de unos segundos se quita :(
Lo que me interesa es poder instalar el paquete, no importa la forma, solo poder instalarlo, ya que lo necesito para que mi aplicación funcione, lo necesito instalado en el servidor.
Agradezco su atención.

Comment: tu app no lo envia como dll al instalar?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, sí la envía como dll pero por alguna razón en mi servidor me marca error, me marca que no lo encuentra, me sale el siguiente error *The CodeDom provider type“Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider” could not be located*